# Using Created and Watcher in VUE.JS

Tags: vue.js

I am using watch and created method for the same data.Is it duplicate code? Is there a better way to do it?

```
props: {  
 regionList: {
   type: Array,
  },
},

data() {
  return {
    regions: [],
  };
},

watch: {
  regionList() {
    if (this.regionList) {
      this.regions = this.regionList;
    }
  },
},
created() {
  if (!this.regionList) {
   this.getApi();
  } else {
   this.regions = this.regionList;
 }
},
```

Comment: Personally I would probably remove the created stuff and just make the watcher an immediate async watcher that handles calling the api if needed.

Comment: Could you provide me an example.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is what immediate watcher is for:

```
watch: {
  regionList: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(newVal) {
      if (newVal.length) {
        this.regions = newVal;
      }
    }
  },
},
created() {
  if (!this.regionList) {
   this.getApi();
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much